# How to downcast numeric columns in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numeric, dtype

How to optimize the data frame memory footprint and find the most optimal (minimal) data types `dtypes` for numeric columns. For example:

```
   A        B    C         D
0  1  1000000  1.1  1.111111
1  2 -1000000  2.1  2.111111

>>> df.dtypes
A      int64
B      int64
C    float64
D    float64
```

Expected result:

```
>>> df.dtypes
A       int8
B      int32
C    float32
D    float32
dtype: object
```

Comment: `d = {'A':np.int8,'B':np.int32,'C':np.float32,'D':np.float32}` and then `df.astype(d)` ?

Comment: Is this helpful: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/168766/234836

Comment: @anky How do you know that `'A'` is `np.int8` and not `np.int32`. I want to get it programmatically.

Comment: Got it. @jezrael's solution should do it then.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use parameter `downcast` in [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with selectig integers and floats columns by [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html), it working from pandas [`0.19+`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.19.0.html?highlight=downcast#downcast-values-to-smallest-possible-dtype-in-to-numeric) like mentioned @anurag, thank you:

```
fcols = df.select_dtypes('float').columns
icols = df.select_dtypes('integer').columns

df[fcols] = df[fcols].apply(pd.to_numeric, downcast='float')
df[icols] = df[icols].apply(pd.to_numeric, downcast='integer')

print (df.dtypes)
A       int8
B      int32
C    float32
D    float32
dtype: object
```

Comment: Just a link to [official pandas doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.19.0.html?highlight=downcast#downcast-values-to-smallest-possible-dtype-in-to-numeric) for downcasting

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that `select_dtypes("float")` doesn't capture all float/complex types (e.g. "float128"), so one might prefer `"floating"` or `"inexact"` instead. See also: [NumPy's dtype hierarchy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html).