# How to determine if a pandas column type can be reduced from int64 to int32 or from float64 to float32?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe which is huge(8 gb). I am trying to find if i will loose any information if i downsize the columns from int64 to int32 or from float64 to float32.

How to find out if the information in dataframe will be lost or not in conversion?

Comment: your float64s won't be float32s by accident.  Whether you need all that precision depends on what its used for

Comment: is there any way to determine if i am loosing precision or not by converting?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65842338/16746253

Comment: Good one @StevenS, did not now about that. Voting to close then.

Comment: Worth mentioning that string columns can be very expensive in terms of memory. The [df.memory_usage()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.memory_usage.html) function is very helpful for diagnosing memory problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a dataframe which is huge(8 gb). I am trying to find if i will loose any information if i downsize the columns from int64 to int32 ...

The simplest way to cast integers to a smaller type and make sure that you are not losing information is to use

```
df['col'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col'], downcast='integer')
```

This will both do the conversion, and check that the conversion didn't lose data. You'll need to do that for each integer column in your dataframe.

> ... or from float64 to float32.

Casting a number to a smaller floating point number always loses some information, unless you are dealing with an exact binary fraction. In practice, you can use 32-bit float if you need around 7 digits or fewer of precision.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check integers, e.g.:

```
df.abs().ge(2 ** 32).to_numpy().any()
```

If it's `False`, you're safe. Otherwise you might have to check column-wise and handle accordingly.

Like [@anon01 mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71027624/how-to-determine-if-a-pandas-column-type-can-be-reduced-from-int64-to-int32-or-f/71027739?noredirect=1#comment125560272_71027624), when it comes to `float`s it really depends on your use case.